# Use arguments with JMS @VirtualPropery

Tags: doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

```
/**
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty 
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("datasByStatus")
 */
public function getNbOfDatasByStatus($status) {
    $datas = $this->getDatas();
    $nbOfDatas = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($datas); $i++){
        if($datas[$i]->isValide() === $status){
         $nbOfDatas ++;
        }
    }
    return $nbOfDatas;
}
```

This keeps failing returning :

```
 "Warning: Missing argument 1 for Bundle\\ModelBundle\\Entity\\MyEntity::getNbOfDatasByStatus(), called in api/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Metadata/PropertyMetadata.php on line 89 and defined
```

I'm sure there is no missing parameter at the different places where this method is called. I've even tried to remove them all and still the error is raised.

If I add a default value to the argument, it works but the actually passed argument is ignored.

I've not found anything searching the docs... Can @VirtualProperty actually handle arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i've not found a documented solution. I think that a workaround is create a generical method to receive the parameter filter and additionally create methods calling it according to business needed with the @VirtualProperty.

Example:

```
function myGenericFilter($parameter)
{
   <do something>
      :
   return result;
}

/**
* @VirtualProperty
**/
function getManagers()
{
    return $this->myFilter(1);
}

/**
* @VirtualProperty
**/
function getStaff()
{
     return $this->myFilter(2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but then you are having two virtual properties instead of one. What I ended up thinking is that wanting to pass a parameter to @VirtualProperty is a misunderstanding of what it actually does. It is supposed to provide a new calculated property at serialization time but not to be called manually. If we want to call some method manually I think we should just use classic public methods.